# string replace doesn't work in powershell

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a problem with powershell.
This is my code:

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText(".\file.js")
$vars = @()

ForEach ($line in $($content -split "`r`n")) {
    if ($line -Match "=") {
        $vars += $line.substring(0,$line.IndexOf("="))
    }
    ForEach ($e in $vars) {
        $line = $line.Replace($e, "$" + $e)
    }
    Write-Host($line)
}
```

And file.js is:

```
x = 123
(x)
```

Output of this code is $x = 123 and (x).
(x) should be ($x). Line `$line = $line.Replace($e, "$" + $e)`
doesn't work.

EDIT:
**Ok. The problem was that $e was equal to `"x "`, not `"x"`.**

Answer (score 0):

You've found the key to solving your own problem by realizing that your attempt to extract `x` from a line such as `x = 123` was flawed in that it extracted `x`  (with a trailing space) instead.

The simplest fix is to simply trim whitespace from the result of your substring-extraction statement (note the `.Trim()` call):

```
# Extract everything before "=", then trim whitespace.
$vars += $line.substring(0,$line.IndexOf("=")).Trim()
```

However, consider streamlining your code as follows:

```
$varsRegex = $sep = ''

# Use Get-Content to read the file as an *array of lines*.
Get-Content .\file.js | ForEach-Object {

  # See if the line contains a variable assignment.
  # Construct the regex so that the variable name is captured via 
  # a capture group, (\w+), excluding the surrounding whitespace (\s).
  if ($_ -match '^\s*(\w+)\s*=') {
    # Extract the variable name from the automatic $Matches variable.
    # [1] represents the 1st (and here only) capture group.
    $varName = $Matches[1]
    # Build a list of variable names as a regex with alternation (|) and
    # enclose each name in \b...\b to minimize false positives while replacing.
    $varsRegex += $sep + '\b' + $varName + '\b'
    $sep = '|'
  }

  # Replace the variable names with themselves prefixed with '$'
  # Note how '$' must be escaped as '$$', because it has special meaning in 
  # the replacement operand; for instance, '$&' refers to what the regex
  # matched in the input string (in this case: a variable name).
  $line = $_ -replace $varsRegex, '$$$&'

  # Output the modified line.
  # Note: Use Write-Host only for printing directly to the screen.
  $line

}
```